# When I use definition instead of class in puppet, what's the best practice for parameters?

Tags: puppet

I realise that it's generally a good idea to create params.pp in the module with modulename::params class and inherit that in modulename class to handle parameters in a separate file. How do I do that if instead of class, I am creating a definition?

Just to clarify, I'm using a definition to be able to install multiple versions of the same application on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Since there is no inheritance available for defined types in Puppet the params.pp patterns can not be reproduced in the exact same way for defined types as for classes. There is another way though.

The following code outputs 'hello world' via the Foo['bar'] defined type:

```
class params {
  $msg = 'hello world'
}
define foo($msg = $params::msg ) {
  notify{ $msg: }
}

foo { 'bar': }
include params
```

Now, for the above to function it is necessary for `params` to be included. Otherwise the Puppet parser will complain that the class params has not been evaluated and therefore the `$params::msg` variable can not be resolved.

It is not necessary to provide ordering between the inclusion of params and the definition of bar, since in Puppet *classes are always evaluated before defined types*. If this would not be so the above would likely cause the same evaluation problem and you would have to write:

```
foo { 'bar':
  require => Class['params'] # <- not necessary
}
include params
```

So for this to work in a module `foo` you can simply add a params class as you are used to and start your init.pp with:

```
include foo::params
define foo($x = $foo::params::x, $y = $foo::params::y, ...)
```

### One important note

Before you happily proceed with the params.pp pattern I advise you to read this blog post: [the problem with params.pp](http://www.devco.net/archives/2013/12/09/the-problem-with-params-pp.php)